SymPy - plot differential equation graph
I get error when trying to plot a graph : TypeError: Cannot convert expression to float
I also get empty graph:
from sympy import *
from IPython.display import display
init_printing()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = symbols('x')
y = Function('y')
ode = Derivative(y(x), x, x) + 9 * y(x)

# Solve the ODE
solution = dsolve(ode, y(x))

# Plot the solution
x_vals = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
y_vals = [solution.rhs.subs({x: val}).evalf() for val in x_vals]

plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y(x)')
plt.title('Solution to y\'\'(x) + 9y(x) = 0')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

python: 3.12
I tried latest Pycharm, Spider(Anaconda) and Jupyter notes (Anaconda)
simply version: 1.13.0
matplotlib: 3.9.1
numpy: 2.0.1
I also tried with lamdify but with same result

x_vals = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)

# Convert the symbolic expression to a numerical function

y_expr = solution.rhs 
 
y_func = lambdify(x, y_expr, modules='numpy')

# Evaluate the solution function for all x_vals
y_vals = y_func(x_vals)
                  

plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals)

plt.grid(True)


plt.show()


enter image description here

Can you add the output of print(solution) to your post? That would help a lot to understand what is going on (both for you and for others).

What about initial conditions? What are the exact error messages?

Your rhs is C1*sin(3*x) + C2*cos(3*x), to be able to plot it you must find the integration constants imposing non-homogeneous initial or boundary conditions.


Your solution.rhs is still undetermined, hence the error.
You need to provide appropriate initial conditions, using the ips keyword argument to dsolve.
Also, the Matplotlib contortions are unneeded, Sympy knows how to plot a Sympy function on itself.
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')
y = Function('y')(x) ; y.dot = y.diff(x) ; y.ddot = y.dot.diff(x)

# Solve the ODE y'' + 9y = 0
solution = dsolve(y.ddot+9*y, ics={y.subs(x,-10):1, y.subs(x,10):1})

# Plot the solution
p = plot(solution.rhs)

I'd like to mention that p is a Plot object whose attributes you can manipulate (but not as much as a Matplotlib Axes…)

As mentioned in the comments, when you solve an ODE you will likely want to provide initial conditions, otherwise you solution will end up containing constants.
Right now, here is what you have:
print(solution)
# out: Eq(y(x), C1*sin(3*x) + C2*cos(3*x))

Note the C1 and C2: those are integration constants. If you know the initial conditions to your problem, you can ask dsolve to solve for them, like this:
# example of initial conditions
initial_conditions = {y(0): 1, y(x).diff(x).subs(x, 0): 0}
solution = dsolve(ode, y(x), ics=initial_conditions)
print(solution)
# out: Eq(y(x), cos(3*x))

Note that the solution doesn't contain C1 and C2 anymore. dsolve was able to compute their values thanks to the initial conditions.
Now to the plot: sympy provides a plot function:
from sympy import plot
plot(solution.rhs, (x, -10, 10), ylabel="y(x)", title="Solution of $%s$" % latex(Eq(ode, 0)))


If you don't like the appearance, you can use matplotlib:
x_vals = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
# convert the symbolic expression to a numerical function for evaluation
f = lambdify(x, solution.rhs)
y_vals = f(x_vals)

plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y(x)')
plt.title('Solution to y\'\'(x) + 9y(x) = 0')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()


